# Codeigniter and Amazon SES : error 554

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send emails with Code Igniter and Amazon SES as smtp server.
Here is the code I use :

```
public function test_mail()
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
        'smtp_user' => 'my_smtp_user',
        'smtp_pass' => 'my_smtp_pass',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'smtp_crypto'  => 'tls'
    );

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('verified@email.com', 'Test From');
    $this->email->to('my_email@email.com', 'Test To');
    $this->email->subject('Test');
    $this->email->message('test');

    $this->email->send();

    var_dump($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Simple code, but not working.

I also tried many host/port combinations without success :(

And here is the var_dump result :

```
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1207641145 

hello: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok

starttls: 220 Ready to start TLS

hello: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok

from: 250 Ok

to: 250 Ok

data: 354 End data with .

554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
The following SMTP error was encountered: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 07:57:17 +0000
From: "Test From" <verified@email.com>
Return-Path: <verified@email.com>
To: my_email@email.com
Subject: Test
Reply-To: "verified@email.com" <verified@email.com>
X-Sender: verified@email.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5644465d8dad1@email.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5644465d8db88"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5644465d8db88
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

test


--B_ALT_5644465d8db88
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

test

--B_ALT_5644465d8db88--
```

Of course, before writing this question, I checked with my colleague in charge of SES if the "from email" is really verified. It is :

[image: Email verified]

I don't know what to or where to look..

Thx :)

Comment: I also found a CI lib for SES but the latest relase is older than me and it's asking secret keys and certs I don't have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happened because SES was in Sandbox. When in Sandbox, both sender and recipient email must be validated, not only the sender.

Comment: I am having the same issue using CE but my SES is not in a sandbox, and I have verified the whole domain